# Perform list of class methods on instance of class

Tags: python, list-comprehension, class-method

If you have a class with several methods, for example

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        return 1
    def b(self):
        return 2
    def c(self):
        return 3
```

How could you call a sequence of `A`'s methods on an instance of `A`? I tried the following

```
>>> foo = A()
>>> l = [A.a, A.b, A.c]
```

When I tried a list comprehension to call each of these methods, I get the following error

```
>>> [foo.f() for f in l]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    [foo.f() for f in l]
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    [foo.f() for f in l]
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'f'
```

If I look at just one of the items in the list, it should be a function object

```
>>> A.a
<function A.a at 0x02F361E0>
```

So how can I call the function on the instance in the list comprehension? It thinks that I am trying to call a method `f`, rather than having `f` take on the values of each of the function objects in `l`.

What I expect the output to be is

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: why not just `[f() for f in l]` ?

Comment: @gabhijit Because these methods have a `self` argument, and therefore need an instance of the class to operate on.

Comment: sorry!!! Then `[f(a) for f in l]` as someone has pointed out. (assuming `a = A()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to pass `foo` object as first (`self`) argument:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def a(self):
   ...:         return 1
   ...:     def b(self):
   ...:         return 2
   ...:     def c(self):
   ...:         return 3
   ...:     

In [2]: foo = A()

In [3]: l = [A.a, A.b, A.c]

In [4]: [f(foo) for f in l]
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is a great solution too! I actually prefer this because it is more generalized, you could maintain the list of class functions, then operate on a number of instances, without having to get a list of each of their bound methods.

Answer (score 4):

I seemed to have figured it out, but I will post an answer in case anyone else runs into this. The list of methods has to be created from the instance itself

```
>>> foo = A()
>>> l = [foo.a, foo.b, foo.c]
>>> [f() for f in l]
[1, 2, 3]
```

The difference is that these methods are actually bound to the `A` instance now

```
>>> foo.a
<bound method A.a of <__main__.A object at 0x02F381B0>>
>>> A.a
<function A.a at 0x02F361E0>
```